# Getting the "diff" between two arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
var array1 = new[] {"A", "B", "C"};
var array2 = new[] {"A", "C", "D"};
```

I would like to get the differences between the two. I know I could write this in just a few lines of code, but I want to make sure I'm not missing a built in language feature or a LINQ extension method.

Ideally, I would end up with the following three results:

- Items not in array1, but are in array2 ("D")
- Items not in array2, but are in array1 ("B")
- Items that are in both

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you've got LINQ available to you, you can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) and [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx). The sets you asked for in the question are respectively:

```
- array2.Except(array1)
- array1.Except(array2)
- array1.Intersect(array2)
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of performance guarantees are one this?  Presumably Except would have to make a sorted copy of each array first.  I can't find any of this on MSDN.

Comment: No, it doesn't make a sorted copy. It creates a set from the excluded sequence, and then iterates over the source sequence, yielding any element which isn't in the excluded sequence.

Comment: (When I say "set" I mean "hash set".)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this would be something I could use in my application, but since my data is presorted and very large, the speed loss is too high.

Comment: I wouldn't discount Linq before having tried it, it and the compiler have a range of optimizations that can make it surprisingly fast. In the latest versions of the framework, AVX extensions are used to produce truly mind-boggling performance in some scenarios. Far faster than even a `for` iteration could do... Try it first, see if it's really as slow as you think it is... I doubt it will be.

Answer (score 13):

from the [MSDN 101 LINQ samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#except1)....

```
public void Linq52() {
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

    IEnumerable<int> aOnlyNumbers = numbersA.Except(numbersB);

    Console.WriteLine("Numbers in first array but not second array:");
    foreach (var n in aOnlyNumbers) {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had to do things similar to this with very large sets of data.  If you're dealing with a few thousand or so, use the Linq stuff since it's much clearer.  But if you know that your arrays are pre-sorted, running a merge like this can do it significantly faster, since it only makes one pass through the data and doesn't need to allocate as much memory as the Linq version.

```
int iA = 0;
int iB = 0;
List<int> inA = new List<int>();
List<int> inB = new List<int>();
List<int> inBoth = new List<int>();
while (iA < numbersA.Length && iB < numbersB.Length)
{
    if (numbersA[iA] < numbersB[iB])
    {
        inA.Add(numbersA[iA++]);
    }
    else if (numbersA[iA] == numbersB[iB])
    {
        inBoth.Add(numbersA[iA++]);
        ++iB;
    }
    else
    {
        inB.Add(numbersB[iB++]);
    }
}
while (iA < numbersA.Length)
{
    inA.Add(numbersA[iA++]);
}
while (iB < numbersB.Length)
{
    inB.Add(numbersB[iB++]);
}
```

Again, this is really only needed if you are dealing with hundreds of thousands of values.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the benchmarks of LINQ extension methods. The results were obtained during the development of a real program.

The tests:
2 lists (lst1 and lst2) each approximately 250000 objects. Each object (class Key) contains a string and an integer. The second list mostly contains the same entries as the first one, but some new entries are added and some are removed.

I tested the Except extension method.

var except = lst2.Except(lst1);

List lst = except.ToList();

These 2 lines produced 600 items list of “new additions”. I timed it using the StopWatch object. The speed is astonishing:**220 ms**. The computer I used is by no means a “speedy Gonzales”.   Core 2 Duo T7700 – 2.4GHz.

Note:

Here is the class Key, which implements IEquatable i-face.

```
public class Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Key(string keyName, int sdIndex)
    {
        this.Name = keyName;
        this.Index = sdIndex;
    }

 // IEquatable implementation
    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return Index.Equals(other.Index) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //Get hash code for the name field if it is not null.
        int hashKeyName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
        //Get hash code for the index field.
        int hashKeyIndex = Index.GetHashCode();
        //Calculate the hash code for the Key.
        return hashKeyName ^ hashKeyIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be like below as well

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 45, 26, 99, 55, 36 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 45, 26, 99, 20, 36 };

var res = arr1.Union(arr2).Except(arr1.Intersect(arr2));
```