# A better way to find a difference between two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the “diff” between two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683310/getting-the-diff-between-two-arrays-in-c)

Is there a better way to get the difference of two arrays?

```
var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };

foreach (var d in a.Except(b).Union(b.Except(a)))
    Console.WriteLine(d); // 1 4
```

Comment: You should define first what is the "difference" between two arrays.

Comment: There are a lot of the same questions on SO

Comment: Sorry if it's a duplicate, my search skills failed me :(

Comment: If it is a duplicate at least point to a real duplicate, I'm asking a better way to find the elements that are not present in both arrays. The linked question does not cover this :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the  [symmetric-difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), an operator that LINQ to Objects doesn't have yet (as of .NET 4.0). The way you've done it is perfectly fine - although you might want to consider extracting that bit out into a method of its own.

However, a more efficient way of accomplishing this would be with the [`HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx) method.

```
var result = new HashSet<int>(a);
result.SymmetricExceptWith(b);

foreach (var d in result)
   Console.WriteLine(d); // 1 4
```

Comment: This seems to be way better than my approach, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
a.Union(b).Except(a.Intersect(b))
```

Comment: To me, this method seems more clear than the method in the original question. Either way is fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have is probably the best way to do this from the standpoint of simple code.

Depending on what your end goal is, there may be ways to make it more readable, though.