# C# two listboxes and two lists

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I'm trying to get two listboxes to work alongside one another. 
I'm using Listbox1, Listbox2, List1 and List2 (for this example), the two lists are for further purposes so they need to be included.

Listbox2 should contain everything of List2, listbox1 should contain everything of List1 except for the items in List2. 
I've been trying alot of different ways, but i just can't seem to get through. 
Currently Listbox2 gets filled and updated perfectly, but i can't seem to get Listbox1 work accordingly.

Options i've tried (might have written it wrongly) :
- add everything of List1 to Listbox1 and then remove everything List2 contains
- loop through every List1 item and check if it existed in List2. Add only if it diden't.

Thanks in advance!

I know i'm adding doubles here. I've tried alot of things and removed everything when trying something new (don't ask why, bad habit)

(AddToListbox is a working method.)

```
if (classroom.members.Count <= 0)
        {
            foreach (Student student in repository.students)
            {
                AddtoListbox(Listbox1, student);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Student student in repository.students)
            {
                foreach (Student studentInClass in classroom.members)
                {
                    if (student.LastName != studentInClass.LastName || student.FirstName != studentInClass.FirstName)
                    {
                        AddtoListbox(Listbox1, student);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, Listbox2 can display stuff in List 2 that is already in List 1, right?

Comment: List1 is a collection of for example 10 students (all excisting students). List2 is a collection of students that are in a certain class, for example 6/10 students (only excisting students)meaning List2 is a part of List1. Listbox1 should show List1 minus List2. In this small example List1 should show 4 students while List2 shows the other 6

Comment: Can you post what you have so far.  My initial thought would be to populate Listbox2 first.  Then when populating Listbox1 use a Foreach and go through each Item in List2 to make sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Kevin Assuming you have LINQ. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683310/getting-the-diff-between-two-arrays-in-c

Comment: I currently populate Listbox2 first and tried looping using a foreach to make sure there are no duplicates when populating listbox1. I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Kevin Share your code and we can figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @KSdev Your code works perfectly, except for one thing. If i add item with index 0 first, i can't add the next one anymore. GIF : 
https://gyazo.com/8362fae5a940cc03f3a0e06d67034ed8

Comment: @Kevin If you can show me your button click event from the video we can determine why the index 0 is causing an issue.  Otherwise you can try and set some breakpoints and see what is different

Comment: I managed to fix the index 0 issue. Your code helped me alot for the rest of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little sample waiting on your code.  I have a button that populates two  `List<int>`.  The First list is 1-20, while the second is 5-9.  You will see that it populates `Listbox1` with 5-9 and `Listbox2` with 1-4 and 10-20.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     list1 = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(5,5));
     list2 = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,20));

     foreach (int num1 in list1)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(num1);
     }

     foreach (int num2 in list2)
     {
         bool numFound = false;
         foreach (int num1 in list1)
         {
             if (num2 == num1)
             {
                 numFound = true;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (!numFound)
             listBox2.Items.Add(num2);
     }
}
```

Not the most eloquent code, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on List1:

```
listbox1.AddRange(List1.Except(List2).Cast<object>.ToArray());
```