# Comparing two arrays in C# and printing the numbers that are missing

Tags: c#, linq

I am pretty new to C# and having trouble checking the difference between two strings with numbers separated by a space and return the numbers that are missing from the second string.

```
   // Initial String with numbers
    string stringA = "503 504 505 506 507 508 503 504 505 506"
    string stringB = "503 504 504 505 506 507 505 508 503 506 505 506 504"

    // I them split them into arrays
    string[] inputArrayA = stringA.Split();
    string[] inputArrayB = stringB.Split();

    // I change them to integers
    int[] numbersA = Array.ConvertAll(inputArrayA, int.Parse);
    int[] numbersB = Array.ConvertAll(inputArrayB, int.Parse);

    // Change the int[] array's to Lists
    var listN = new List<int>(numbersA);
    var listM = new List<int>(numbersB);

    // Compare the lists and put in an array the numbers that are missing from listN
    var missinNumbers = listM.Except(listN).ToList();

    // Print List contents
    missinNumbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

But this is not working right now.
I tried implementing a separate method using HashSet. But for some reason missinNumbers is always empty.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindMissing(IEnumerable<int> mainList, IEnumerable<int> listToCompare)
{
    // Compare lists and return values that aren't in mainList but are in listToCompare
    HashSet<int> convertedToHash = new HashSet<int>(mainList);
    convertedToHash.ExceptWith(listToCompare);
    return convertedToHash;
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I went through all the possible solutions suggested for comparing two arrays in C# and tried different approaches with LINQ and with two for loops but I could not figure it out with either.
Thanks for the help.

EDIT :
My goal is to print the numbers that are missing from stringA compared to stringB. So, if we sort the two arrays, we can see that missing numbers are :
504 505 506.

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your initial code?

Comment: The `Except` is working exactly like it should - there are no numbers in the second list that don't exist in the first. Some just appear more times. What is your desired output?

Comment: What do you expect the missing numbers to be?

Comment: [Getting the “diff” between two arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/683310/215552). Also, "not working" is quite nebulous. Provide the error, what you expected to happen that didn't, and/or what happened that you didn't expect.

Comment: As the question is posed, the code you have is correct.  There are no missing numbers, both sets contain the numbers 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, and 508.  They only vary in the quantity and order, but that isn't what your question asked, nor what your code checks.  It would be helpful if you provided what output you desire.

Comment: My goal is to print the numbers that are missing from stringA compared to stringB. So, if we sort the two arrays, we can see that missing numbers are :
504 505 506.

Comment: try listN.Except(listM)

Comment: Be aware that using a HashSet will prevent you from seeing what duplicates are missing.  When utilizing a Set though, the set operation you're looking for is called "[Symmetric Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)," which is the items that DO NOT appear in both collections.  However, since you only care about what doesn't appear in the second string vs the first including duplication differences, then, @Dragos answer would suit you best.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a Dictionary where the key is the string ("503" etc) and the value is the number of occurrences of that element (so if 503 repeats 3 times the key value pair will be <503, 3>).

You can create 2 dictionaries for the 2 lists, then iterate through one of them and lookup elements in the second, subtract the number of occurrences to find out how many elements for that key are left.

> In your case the dictionaries would look like

A__________B__________Result

<503, 2>___<503, 2>____

<504, 1>___<504, 3>____504, 2 more occurence in list B

...etc

Here is how you could do it in C#

```
string stringA = "503 504 505 506 507 508 503 504 505 506";
string stringB = "503 504 504 505 506 507 505 508 503 506 505 506 504";

// linq to make dictionary from A
var mapA = stringA.Split().GroupBy(a => a)
                          .Select(a => new {a.Key,Count = a.Count()})
                          .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Count);

// linq to make dictionary from B
var mapB =  stringB.Split().GroupBy(b => b)
                           .Select(b => new { b.Key, Count = b.Count() })
                           .ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Count);

// Elements that are in B but not in A 
var BminusA = mapB.Select(b => { int aCount; 
                                 return new {b.Key, Value = b.Value - (mapA.TryGetValue(b.Key, out aCount) ? aCount: 0)};})
                  .Where(difference => difference.Value > 0);
```

The above will also give you the count of the missing numbers (1 in each case for {504, 505, 506}).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, my previous answer assumed there was something "wrong" with the code, and I didn't look at it more thoroughly. As has been said, `Except` doesn't take quantity into account when performing its checks, only if an element exists in another list *at all*. There's a LINQ way to do what you want, but doing it manually is easier to read (not to mention probably faster).

```
for (int i = 0; i < listN.Count; i++)
{
    if (listM.Remove(listN[i]))
    {
        listN.RemoveAt(i--);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < listM.Count; i++)
{
    if (listN.Remove(listM[i]))
    {
        listM.RemoveAt(i--);
    }
}
```

After this, `listN` will be populated by all the specific elements that are not present in `listM` and vice versa.

If you want to join both difference lists into a single collection, you can simply do:

```
var differences = new List<int>(listM);
differences.AddRange(listN);
```

Comment: I like how you remove an item and step the index back at the same time. It took me a second to realize what you were doing, but once it clicked it made perfect sense. I'm going to have to borrow that pattern. I have always kept a separate list of the removals and worked backwards to keep indexes from changing.

Comment: I see it works but I am not sure I understand how exactly. I'm adding a bunch of print's to figure it out but maybe one of you guys can explain it better. Initially I tried with two for loops but the second was inside the first one...

Comment: .Remove takes out the first instance of its parameter and returns true if that parameter existed. By removing each string from listM(stringB) as you come across it in listN(stringA) you are left with only the missing numbers. You really only need the first loop to get the answer you asked for. The second loop gives you the opposite (found in listN but missing in listM)

Comment: Ok, I understand. How about this - listN.RemoveAt(i--); Is the idea of it to reset the for loop to always loop from index 0 ? I thought -1 index goes backwards on the iterable. At least it was like that in Python, so I am abit confused about it.

Comment: @burizz The decrement is to counteract the offset of indices that comes with the call to `RemoveAt`. Without it, you would end up skipping the element after the one you removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? We get the count of each distinct string in list b, and if the difference between that and the count from list a is positive, we add that many copies of the string to a missing list.

```
        string[] stringA = "503 504 505 506 507 508 503 504 505 506".Split();
        string[] stringB = "503 504 504 505 506 507 505 508 503 506 505 506 504".Split();

        List<int> missingNumbers = new List<int>();

        foreach (string num in stringB.Distinct())
        {
            int difference = stringB.Where(x => x == num).Count() - stringA.Where(x => x == num).Count();
            for (int i = difference; i > 0; i--)
            {
                missingNumbers.Add(int.Parse(num));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go ready up some more on LINQ because I do not think I understand this part very well: int difference = stringB.Where(x => x == num).Count() - stringA.Where(x => x == num).Count();

Comment: stringB.Where places each item from stringB into x, checks if x == num, and if it does, it adds x to the return collection. So if stringB contains 1 2 2 3 4 4 and num = 4, stringB.Where(x => x == num) would return a collection with 2 copies of 4 in it.

Answer (score 0):

To provide some feedback on this in case it may be useful to someone. Here is my final solution. It solved all test cases in my exercise except one. Where we have 1 000 000 integers in each array. What would be an efficient way of doing that if we have two strings of over a milion numbers in each separated by a space.

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    // Build Array N from input numbers
    string[] inputLineN = Console.ReadLine().Split();

    // Build Array M from second input numbers
    string[] inputLineM = Console.ReadLine().Split();

    // Convert to int[] array
    int[] numbersN = Array.ConvertAll(inputLineN, int.Parse);
    int[] numbersM = Array.ConvertAll(inputLineM, int.Parse);

    // Convert them to Lists
    var listN = new List<int>(numbersN);
    var listM = new List<int>(numbersM);

    for (int index = 0; index < listN.Count; index++)
    {
        // Remove first occurance of item from listM if it exists in listN
        if (listM.Remove(listN[index]))
        {
            // Remove listN[index] and decrement the index to -1 so that the next iteration
            // starts from 0 again otherwise we will start at 1 and skip an item
            listN.RemoveAt(index--);
        }
    }

    // Sort missing items and join them back in a single string
    listM.Sort();
    int[] removeDuplicates = listM.Distinct().ToArray();
    string missingNumbers = string.Join(" ", removeDuplicates);

    Console.WriteLine(missingNumbers);
}
```

Comment: Your current solution has multiple issues, which will make the Time complexity and space complexity worse as the amount of data will increase,  couple of issues as I can see:

1. Converting string to integer (not required), you are not doing any integer specific operation, just comparing the elements, for string can be used as well

2. Removing from the original List will alter the original data for any other operation, you have to retain a separate copy.

Comment: Check out the solution, I have posted, that would be the simplest to achieve your use case and would be fast also, though time complexity would be O(N^2), we can make is better by converting List to Hashset, which does the search in O(logN) and overall complexity would become O(NLogN)