# Unmatched elements in 2 different Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, compare, missing-data

Let say, I'm having 2 different arrays. The first is
`x[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` and the second one is `y[] = {1, 3, 4}`. The output that I expected is `z[] = {0, 2}`. How can i do this in C#?

Note: I'm also expecting the `z[]` elements are ordered ascending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683310/getting-the-diff-between-two-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Linq,

```
    int[] x = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] y = new int[]{1, 3, 4};
    var result = x.Where(i => !y.Contains(i)).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

---

Using Set operation `Except()`

```
var result = x.Except(y);
```

If you are using `Except()`, then read below note from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in
> second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear
> in first. **Only unique elements are returned.**

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fSFn50)

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet gives, sorted unmatched elements in two arrays as result;

```
int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
int[] y = new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 4, 5 };

int[] result = x.Except(y).Union(y.Except(x)).ToArray();
Array.Sort(result);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', result)); // Output: 0 2 5
```